# How do I SSH into my desktop from a windows computer if my username has a space in it?

Tags: windows, ssh, command, command-prompt, openssh

I've tried to do ssh "first last"@address, first_last@address, "first_last"@address and none of those have worked. Is there a way to ssh into it? I keep getting the error "ssh: connect to host (my IP address) port 22: Connection timed out"

Comment: Your Unix user name really has a space in it?  Perhaps your Windows one does but it's highly unlikely your Unix one does.  Generally you only use alphanumeric characters in a user name.  However, a connection timeout has nothing to do with your user name - there is something else like a network configuration or other issue.

Comment: @stdunbar Sorry I forgot to clarify, I am talking about having a space in my windows username

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem in ssh with space in Windows username, it worked when I used

```
ssh "first last"@myIPaddress
```

(your first attempt).